# HTML Value finding

Tags: javascript, html

I know that "this.value" can get the value of the `<option>` tag:

```
<select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
  <option value="">Select a person:</option>
  <option value="1">Peter Griffin</option>
  <option value="2">Lois Griffin</option>
  <option value="3">Joseph Swanson</option>
  <option value="4">Glenn Quagmire</option>
  </select>
```

But how to get a value (value="IE") from the `<a>` tag, because this doesn't work:

```
<a href="#" value="IE" onclick="showUser(this.value)">Click</a>
```

Comment: `value` isn't a valid attribute on an `<a>` tag anyway...

Comment: you sure the **a** tag has an attribute _value_ ? because as far aa I know, it does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The attribute `value` in `a` tag doesn't exist. You can check the W3C Reference in https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/a.html#a-attributes.

You could use HTML5 Dataset. (`data-value="IE"`).

You don't need to add an `id` attribute in your `a` tag.

Just remove the `.value` in `onclick="showUser(this.value)"`. By using `this` you can access all the **attributes** of the tag.

**Something like this with pure JavaScript:**

```js
function showUser(elem) {
  alert(elem.getAttribute("data-value"));
}
```

```html
<a href="#" data-value="IE" onclick="showUser(this)">Click</a>
```

Comment: Maybe this would be the best one. I'll try it on my website.

Comment: Why are you using showUser(elem), not a showUser()?

Comment: `elem` is an parameter which is the DOM reference. By using `this` you can access all the attributes of the tag in this way.

Comment: I think I will use it a bit later because I found the fastest solution. I will keep it mind that :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [getAttribute](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getattribute.asp),

```
<a href="#" value="IE" onclick="alert(this.getAttribute('value'))">Click</a>
```

Check the [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/3vwb8k6m/)

Comment: I found this as the best solution because you have to write only one line of code.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of doing this in pure Javascript is probably

```
document.getElementById('anyId').value
```

The HTML tag will not count as an object, but an element, so therefore you rather want ot use the getElement function.
The full implementation of this code in your case would be:

```
<a href="#" value="IE" id="click" onclick="showUser(document.getElementById('click').value)">Click</a>
```

Comment: Won't help either.

Comment: So it would be an ID of <a> tag and document.getElementById('anyId').value line I should write in the showUser  function?

Comment: @Lukas Exactly, look at the edit i just did. Might need a little cleaning up, if you want to i can do a pen and link it to you.

Answer (score 0):

May be this approach will help you :

`<a href="#" value="IE" onclick="showUser(event)">Click</a>`

```
function showUser(event){
    console.log(event.target.value);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using value attribute which I am not sure is an attribute of anchor tag,you can use rel attribute and assign ur value in it. Now, you can  easily get your value like this:
$('#yourid').attr('rel');

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<a href="#" value="IE" onclick="showUser(this)">Click</a>

function showUser(elem) {
  console.log(elem.getAttribute("value"));
}
```